# New to IIS, looking for a way to handle logs and sessions upon a deploy

Tags: iis

Deploying a ASP.Net application via Teamcity and a Nant scripts.  Currently I am zipping up the directory from the local git repository (after building) and copying up to the test machine,  Renaming the current web home directory and dropping in the new one.  (with some scripts to get the web.config in place)

The question I have is how to handle the log and sessions directories.  I want them in the current deployed directory but don't want to have to copy them from the old to new one.  I was debated about having them stored in a different directory then the web home directory and just placing a shortcut pointing at that directory (would be in git so it would get deployed with everything else).  In linux I have a link (ln) doing this very thing for me.

Is their a cleaner solution?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of renaming the current web directory, copy it and then use NAnt's `<delete />` task to delete the web directory excluding the log and session directories.  Then simply unzip the new web application.

For example:

```
<delete>
  <fileset basedir="${PublishLocation}">
    <include name="**/*"/>
    <exclude name="**/Logs/**/*" />
    <exclude name="**/Sessions/**/*" />
  </fileset>
</delete>
```